# How can I call beforeSave methods recursively while saving associative data in CakePHP 3?

Tags: rest, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, crud

I am trying to write a REST Api using CakePHP 3.

I have two tables Documents and DocumentImages, when I send POST request with body:

```
{
   "description": "Short Desc.",
   "company_id": 2,
   "department_id": 3,
   "status": 0,
   "document_images":[
    {
        "base64" : "xyz"

    },
    {
        "base64" : "abc"
    }
   ]

}
```

It saves both to Documents and DocumentImages and makes the document_id of images as it must be.

Now, I need to do something after saving the document and before saving the images, however beforeSave function in images never be called, so it saves both of the entities in DocumentsController.

What can I do for catch the event after the document saved but before the images save?

By the way, if anyone suggest a solution using CRUD I will be very appreciate.

Comment: Put your logic in the **afterSave()** callback for Documents

Comment: But in afterSave() callback for Documents the document_images also saved I need them before saved to DB

Comment: I wonder if your table associations are all set up correctly, as it should be calling beforeSave for your images. Maybe check the types of the entities you have after your patchEntity call to make sure that they are what you expect them to be.